# How do I edit a string in Matlab so that it only contains letters A-Z

Tags: regex, matlab, unique, edit

I need to be able to edit a string in Matlab so that it only contains letters a-z.

Example:

If I have the words

```
dog 
cat
fish
°·°·°·
∞°¥È
¥©±∏≥™
¥Î„‚Ω‚‡Ó
```

I want to be able to edit this list so that the only words I get are

```
dog
cat
fish
```

Currently, the way I am editing the words is using regexp() as shown below.

```
pat = '[\s\.\]\[\&\%\#\*\,\$\_\ ,;:-''"?!/()@=><]+'; 
words = regexp(st,pat,'split');
words = lower(words);
```

This method works well for removing quite a bit of the symbols that I don't want but there has been a few exceptions, including the ones I listed above, that I want to remove.

Comment: Doesn't `\W` suffice? Or `[^A-Za-z]`?

Comment: What Biffen said should work. You could also delete those characters with `regexprep`, leaving the case unchanged.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Ok, deleted.

Comment: @Jan I think I was right, [here's the doc if you're interested](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#input_argument_expression).

Comment: I think the tricky part is correctly dealing with new line characters. If I understand the example right the new line characters between words should be preserved.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Daniel you can always transform to a cell of strings, and delete the noise, right?

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I tried using the \W and [^A-Za-z] inside my pat variable but it didn't seem to work, maybe I am writing it wrong. Also, the problem with ignoring just the specific characters I listed is that I do not know what characters I will encounter beforehand, I have a lot of files I have to look through and dont know whats in them.

Comment: how are you reading in the file? do you use dlmread csvread textscan?

Comment: fid=fopen(fileName,'r');
st = fread(fid,'*char')';
fclose(fid);
pat = '[\W\.\]\[\&\%\#\*\,\$\_\ ,;:-''"?!/()@=><]+';
words = regexp(st,pat,'split');
words = lower(words); 
[uniqueWords, ~, intLabels] = unique(words); 
count = histc(intLabels, 1:numel(uniqueWords));

Comment: I was able to use the \W in my pattern and it worked a little better but I am still having problems with these:

™
·
‚‡Ó
È
Î„‚,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
for i=length(string):-1:1
    if string[i]<int8('a') || (string[i]>int8('z') && string[i]<int8('A')) || string[i]>int8('Z')
        string=[string(1:i-1) string(i+1:end);
    end
end
```

Not the most efficient or elegant thing in the world, but will probably work.

Also, if you don't want to use loops, you can do something like:

```
condition = str>='a' & str <='z'; % | ...
string=string[condition];
```

Comment: I have to go through thousands of files and extract words from them, I really don't want to use any more loops. Thanks though.

Comment: Understandable. Maybe that suits better what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is definitely closer to what I am looking for, my only problem now is that my words are in a cell array and the operators <= and >= don't seem to work with cell arrays. Thanks.